# I need to fetch master record and potential match from the column match result in my table which having same groupid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, msbi

I have one table in which there are many records, now I need to fetch master record and potential match records from my column match result which having same groupid on the basis of it's top parented.

[image]

Comment: please provide some sample test data and expected result

Comment: please see the image

Comment: images might be blocked in some domains,

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want something like

```
select *
from [table] as master
inner join [table] as match on master.groupid = match.groupid
where master.match_result = 'Master Record'
and match.match_result = 'Potential Match'
```